# Bra size validation with RegExp (US, EU, Japan, Australia)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to check if an input is a valid bra measurement. In the US, bra sizes are written with an even number 28-48 and a letter A-I, AAA, AA, DD, DDD, HH or HHH. The EU, Japan and Australia use different numbers and patterns, ex. 90C C90 and DD6.

-I want to split the letters and digits, check that the letter is between A - I or AA, AAA, DD, DDD, HH or HHH, and that the number is 28 - 48 (even numbers only), 60-115 (increments of 5, so 65, 70, 75, etc.) or 6-28 even numbers only.

`var input = $("#form_input").val("");`

`var bust = input.match(/[\d\.]+|\D+/g);`

`var vol = bust[0];`

`var band = bust[1];`

I can write a long test condition:

if ((vol > 28 && vol < 48) && band == "AAA" || band == "AA" || band == "A" || band == "B" || etc.) { //some code

} else { error message" }```

How do I shorten this and do the above things using regex?

Comment: `var input = $("#form_input").val("");` So you are storing a jquery object into input and setting the inputs value to an empty string. That would than fire an error since a jQuery object does not have a match() method.

Comment: `/(\d{2})([A-I]|A{2,3}|D{2,3}|H{2,3})/`

Comment: Doesn't work for `28AA`.

Comment: `/(2[89]|3[0-9]|4[0-8])([A-I]|A{2,3}|D{2,3}|H{2,3})/` or `/(28|[34][02468])([A-I]|A{2,3}|D{2,3}|H{2,3})/`

Comment: Neither work for `34AAA`.

Comment: the [A-I] would need to be bumped to the end, it is late and did not test

Comment: It would helpful if you could edit to provide some examples, providing a brief explanation why each is or is not a valid measurement.

Comment: Regex is terrible at handling increments and ranges.  And since the formatting of my code varies depending on the country it made it even harder. Many of your comments lead me to a solution, which you can find here: https://playcode.io/668437/.

Comment: I still feel like there is a better way so if anyone wants to play around with it still you can use this bra measurement chart as a guide: https://www.sizeguide.net/bra-sizes.html.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit of a long pattern with the alternatives, but you can easily adjust the ranges if something is missing or matches too much.

You can first check if the pattern matches using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). To get the band and the vol matches, one option is to extract either the digits or the uppercase chars from the match as there are matches for example for `90C` and  `C90`

```
^(?:(?:28|3[02468]|4[02468])(?:AA?|[BC]|D{1,4}|[E-I])|(?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I])|[A-I](?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])|(?:[68]|1[02468]|2[0246])(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I]))$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `(?:28|3[02468]|4[02468])` Match from 28 - 48 in steps of 2
  - `(?:AA?|[BC]|D{1,4}|[E-I])` Match AA, A, B, C, 1-4 times a D or a range E-I
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])` Match from 60 - 115 insteps of 5
  - `(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I])` Match AA, A, B, C DD, D or a range E-I
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-I](?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])` Match a range A-I and a number 60 - 115 in steps of 5
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[68]|1[02468]|2[0246])` Match from 6 - 26 in steps of 2
  - `(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I])` Match AA, A, B, C, DD, D or a range E-I
- `)` Close alternation
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJfqyx/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:(?:28|3[02468]|4[02468])(?:AA?|[BC]|D{1,4}|[E-I])|(?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I])|[A-I](?:[6-9][05]|1[01][05])|(?:[68]|1[02468]|2[0246])(?:AA?|[BC]|DD?|[E-I]))$/;
const str = `28A
28AA
30B
34AA
36DDDD
D70
I115
A70
H80
6AA
26I
`;

str.split('\n').forEach(s => {
  if (pattern.test(s)) {
    console.log(`Match: ${s}`);
    let vol = s.match(/\d+/)[0];
    let band = s.match(/[A-Z]+/)[0];
    console.log(`vol: ${vol}`);
    console.log(`band: ${band}`);
    console.log("---------------------------------------");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Much needed!

Comment: the explanation helped a lot. I'll give an update so everyone can see the finished product. Maybe another week or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(((([0-4])(0|2|4|6|8))|(6|8))|(((6|7|8|9)(0|5))|(1[01][05])))((AAA)|(AA)|(DD)|(DDD)|(HH)|(HHH)|[A-I])$
```

Proof that all valid sizes match, while all `100_464` sample invalid sizes do not:

```js
const validNumbers = Array
  .from({ length: 22 }, (_, i) => 6 + (i * 2))
  .concat(Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => 60 + (i * 5)));
  
const validLetters = [
  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
  'AAA', 'AA', 'DD', 'DDD', 'HH', 'HHH'
];

const validSizes = validNumbers.map((number) => validLetters
  .map((letter) => number + letter))
  .flat();

const invalidNumbers = Array
  .from({ length: 1_000 }, (_, i) => i)
  .filter((n) => !validNumbers.includes(n))

const invalidLetters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
  .map((letter) => Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, i) => letter.repeat(i + 1)))
  .flat();

const invalidSizes = invalidNumbers.map((number) => invalidLetters
  .map((letter) => number + letter))
  .flat();

const regex = /^(((([0-4])(0|2|4|6|8))|(6|8))|(((6|7|8|9)(0|5))|(1[01][05])))((AAA)|(AA)|(DD)|(DDD)|(HH)|(HHH)|[A-I])$/;

const falsePositives = invalidSizes.filter((size) => regex.test(size));
console.log({ falsePositives });
console.log({ validSizes: validSizes.map((size) => ({ size, isValid: regex.test(size) })) });
```

Comment: Impressive! I had to also consider that the users input would be reserved so it could be 90C or C90. For that reason, most of the regex had to be scrapped. Feedback on this welcomed: https://playcode.io/668437/